# List of classes with decreased code coverage since last commit/run

Tags: junit, jenkins, report, sonarqube, cobertura

we have strict rules for code coverage in our project. And using jenkins/sonar/cobertura to check it. Do you know whether and how could I get list of all classes which code coverge **decreased** since last commit/run?

E.g.: big project with thousands of classes, big issue with tens of touched/changed classes... and analyse gives me only overal statistics, or statistics per package/class which I have to traverse by hand. I would like to see info box with list of classes A and B which code coverage decrease and X which conditional coverage decreased. Its mean I forgot to add/update junit tests for these classes.

Thanks, have a nice day.
  W

Comment: Cobertura can generate reports for you (XML / HTML). Just write a script to run through those reports, compare them to the previous reports, and generate your own statistics based on their change.